# Python: Keep the existing line if not add a new line in a file?

Tags: python, nagios

I want to keep the existing line if the existing value is present, or else add the line to the file. I'm writing the script for nagios host file.

**Host file:**

```
define host{
          use             hoststatus
          host_name       linuxhost1
          alias           linuxhost1
          hostgroups      linuxgroup
          Sev             1
}
define host{
          use             hoststatus
          host_name       linuxhost2
          alias           linuxhost2
          hostgroups      linuxgroup
          Sev             2
}
define host{
          use             hoststatus
          host_name       linuxhost3
          alias           linuxhost3
          hostgroups      linuxgroup
}

define host{
          use             hoststatus
          host_name       linuxhost4
          alias           linuxhost4
          hostgroups      linuxgroup
}
```

I have written this script that adds the line if the line is not present (i.e Sev line is not present in last two host, so if the Sev *is* present skip it) For the first two hosts I don't want to add anything.

**Code:**

```
import re,sys

with open(sys.argv[1],'r') as f1:
    data = f1.readlines()

txt=''

with open(sys.argv[1],'r') as f3:
    severity=True
    default=4
    vmowner=True
    default_VM = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX"

    for line in f3:
        if line.strip().startswith('Sev'):
            severity=False

        if line.strip().startswith('Vmowner'):
            vmowner=False

    if severity:
        txt = txt + "\tSev\t\t" + str(default) + "\n"

    if vmowner:
        txt = txt + "\tVmowner\t\t" + str(default_VM) + "\n"
    txt = txt + "\tSevOwner\tYYYYYYYYYYYY\n"
    txt = txt + "}\n"

with open(sys.argv[1],'r+') as f2:
    for line in data:
        if line.strip().startswith('}'):
            line = line.replace('}',txt)
#        f2.write(line)
        print line,
```

But the issue is I'm not getting the exact output.

**Generated output:**

```
define host{
          use             hoststatus
          host_name       linuxhost1
          alias           linuxhost1
          hostgroups      linuxgroup
          Sev             1
        Vmowner         XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
        SevOwner        YYYYYYYYYYYY
}

define host{
          use             hoststatus
          host_name       linuxhost2
          alias           linuxhost2
          hostgroups      linuxgroup
          Sev             2
        Vmowner         XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
        SevOwner        YYYYYYYYYYYY
}

define host{
          use             hoststatus
          host_name       linuxhost3
          alias           linuxhost3
          hostgroups      linuxgroup
        Vmowner         XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
        SevOwner        YYYYYYYYYYYY
}


define host{
          use             hoststatus
          host_name       linuxhost4
          alias           linuxhost4
          hostgroups      linuxgroup
        Vmowner         XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
        SevOwner        YYYYYYYYYYYY
}
```

**Expected output:**

```
define host{
          use             hoststatus
          host_name       linuxhost1
          alias           linuxhost1
          hostgroups      linuxgroup
          Sev             1
        Vmowner         XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
        SevOwner        YYYYYYYYYYYY
}

define host{
          use             hoststatus
          host_name       linuxhost2
          alias           linuxhost2
          hostgroups      linuxgroup
          Sev             2
        Vmowner         XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
        SevOwner        YYYYYYYYYYYY
}

define host{
          use             hoststatus
          host_name       linuxhost3
          alias           linuxhost3
          hostgroups      linuxgroup
          Sev             4
          Vmowner         XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
          SevOwner        YYYYYYYYYYYY
}


define host{
          use             hoststatus
          host_name       linuxhost4
          alias           linuxhost4
          hostgroups      linuxgroup
          Sev             4
          Vmowner         XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
          SevOwner        YYYYYYYYYYYY
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I would do:

- Read the entire file
- split it into blocks
- split each block into lines
- add any needed data
- remake the entire block
- remake the entire file

---

```
from collections import OrderedDict

default_sev = 4
default_VM = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
default_sevowner = "YYYYYYYYYYYY"

def add_missing(data_block):
    data_block = data_block.strip("}\n")
    lines = OrderedDict([line.split() for line in data_block.splitlines()])
    if "Sev" not in lines:
        lines["Sev"] = default_sev
    if "Vmowner" not in lines:
        lines["Vmowner"] = default_VM
    if "SevOwner" not in lines:
        lines["SevOwner"] = default_sevowner
    data = ""
    for key, value in lines.items():
        data += "          {: <16}{}\n".format(key, value)
    return "define host{{\n{}\n}}".format(data)

with open(sys.argv[1]) as f1:
    data = f1.read()

blocks = data.split('define host{') #split into blocks
blocks = filter(None, blocks) #remove empty blocks

with open(sys.argv[1], 'w') as f1:
    for block in blocks:
        f1.write(add_missing(block))
```

Comment: when i ran your code i got this error   print add_missing(block)
  File "file.py", line 19, in add_missing
    data += "          {: <16}{}\n".format(key, value)
ValueError: zero length field name in format

Comment: You must be using a very old version of python. Change it to `data += "          {0: <16}{1}\n".format(key, value)`

Answer (score 0):

You are not resetting the severity flag to true after each host. This means that the first host sets the flag to false, and then the later if statement checking for the flag can never be entered. You need to add logic to check for the beginning of a new host file to reset logic like your severity flag.

Comment: I have found that already. any idea how to do it differently ?

Comment: Depending on how much parsing you are doing, you may need a more robust approach. But a simple answer would be to add another line check in your for loop: if line.strip().startswith('define host'): severity = True

Comment: I have added the some logic but the for loop for Sev repeats multiple times for that host.

Comment: In the code you posted, I do not see how you check for the end of a host definition. You would need to add logic to check for the end of a host definition (I guess just check for '}' in this case), then add things like the Sev if the flag was set, then reset all the flags.